# how to get value in text field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have one text field and setting its name & values from php, like:

```
<input type="text" id="qtyProductID_' . $productID . '" 
  size="3" value="' . $totalItems . '" >
```

i also have image button for click event

```
<a href=fun.php?action=update&productID=' . $productID . ' 
  onClick="return false;"><img 
  src="images/update.jpg" id="updateProductID_' . $productID . '"></a>
```

now after click in JS file i want to get value of text field i click

```
var productIDValSplitter = (this.id).split("_");
var productIDVal = productIDValSplitter[1]; 
var tqty = $('#qtyProductID_'.productIDVal[1]).attr('value');   
alert(tqty);
```

i am getting error

i am looking for how to set the variable name in

```
$('#qtyProductID_'.productIDVal[1])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript the plus (+) sign is used for string concatenation, so

```
$('#qtyProductID_'+productIDVal[1]).attr('value');
```

but just like brad said, it can be written as

```
$('#qtyProductID_'+productIDVal[1]).val();
```

because jQuery offers a unified method of getting values from form input fields, not just  `<input>`, but `<select>` and `<textarea>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

.val() is what you're looking for

```
$("#someInput").val()
```

What's the error?

Comment: No i am not looking for that, i am looking for how to set the variable in line $('#qtyProductID_'.productIDVal[1])